# Подключение по FTP к виртуальной машине

Tags: ftp

Можно ли реализовать подобное? На виртуалке стоит Ubuntu на которой хочу развернуть Asterisk,но работать с кодом хочу из под винды.

Comment: поставьте пакет с ftp и работайте. Можно. Разрешаем

Comment: Детальнее чуть можно?

Comment: Тут https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server, Тут http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/server/ftp.html. Интернет большой

Comment: спасибо будем пробовать